# Upload video to myspace

Tags: api, file-upload, myspace

I am working on an application to upload videos, and I am trying to find out if the Myspace API supports video upload.  But I can't find it in his forum, is there some alternate way I can allow users to do it?

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of the MySpace API, you can upload video using the OpenSocial endpoints. More information can be found here: http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=OpenSocial_0.9_MediaItems

Answer (score 0):

use Myspace android sdk, and on it use the sample project and put your keys instead of consumer keys and secret keys.